# Select statement to convert phone type

Tags: adfs, claims

I have a custom claims rule in ADFS, and the way the database is set up, we have a table that goes by PhonetypeID. The PhonetypeID then corresponds to a certain phone type(i.e. home, cell, work, other). I am getting an error in ADFS because these are invalid columns that I have in my custom claims rule. How can I convert the phonetypeid to the claims that need to be sent? the phonetypeid's are as follows: 1 = Home 2 = Cell 3 = Work 4 = Other Here is the select statement in the claims rule:

```
query = "SELECT     Firstname,Lastname,email,middleinitial,suffix,credential,npi,userGUID,workphone,mobilephone    , Firstname + ' ' + Lastname 
 as displayname from ADFSUserView WHERE Username = {0}", param = regexreplace(c.Value,     "(?<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?<user>.+)", "${user}"));
```

How can I convert the phone types 2 and 3 to the claims i have, which are workphone and mobilephone?

Answer (score 0):

Please display the whole rule. Also please expand on what phonetypeid map to what claims. What has that could to do with the regex?

There's an example of valid SQL syntax at the end of [Understanding Claim Rule Language in AD FS 2.0 & Higher](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4792.understanding-claim-rule-language-in-ad-fs-2-0-higher.aspx).

And regex examples at [AD FS 2.0: Using RegEx in the Claims Rule Language](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16161.ad-fs-2-0-using-regex-in-the-claims-rule-language.aspx).

I normally do something like this in two steps:

- Put the attributes that you want to change into temp claims e.g. http://company.com/temp1
- Make this an add not an issue
- Then do the regexreplace on the temp claim and issue to the claim you want